# How can I address columns of included tables in where clause?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following select statement, with a not working where clause:

```
 Comment.findAll({
              where:{
               $or: {
                    id : {
                        $like: 11
                    },
                    'posts.id': {
                        $like: 23
                    },
                    'autors.id': {
                        $like: 2
                    }
                }
              },
              include: [{
                 model: Post,
                 attributes: [],
                 include: [{
                    model: Author,
                    attributes: []

                 }]
               }]
             })
```

In my where clause, I would like to address the columns of my included tables. For instance `select where posts.id is like 1000`. What is the appropriate syntax to achieve this?

As far as I know, using `where` within the include, is not what I want, because of the necessary `$or`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
Comment.findAll({
              where:{
               $or: {
                    id : {
                        $like: 11
                    },
                    '$post.id$': {
                        $like: 23
                    },
                    '$post.autor.id$': {
                        $like: 2
                    }
                }
              },
              include: [{
                 model: Post,
                 attributes: [],
                 include: [{
                    model: Author,
                    attributes: []

                 }]
               }]
             })
```